# Translate spanish characters to english for field values

Tags: class, map, string, replaceall, key

I have a requirement to translate few predetermined spanish characters to english in field values of different custom objects. I have tried to create a generic code. can someone please let me know where it fails to give desired output?

Apex class snippet:

```
public static String translate(String str)
{
  M= new Map<String,String>{'á'=>'a', 'é'=>'e' ,'í'=>'i', 'ó'=>'o', 'ú'=>'u', 'ü'=>'u', 'ñ'=>'n'};

  for (String key: M.keyset())//iterate over keyset
  {
    str.replace(key,M.get(key));//Get CORR Value
  }

  return str;//english
}
```

Comment: What error do you get, if any?

Comment: I am not getting any error in debug log but simply this desired translation I am not getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replace() function does not edit the variable you put in front of it but returns a new String. Please replace:

```
str.replace(key,M.get(key));//Get CORR Value
```

with:

```
str = str.replace(key,M.get(key));//Get CORR Value
```