# Translate Spanish characters to english

Tags: apex, trigger, class, customsetting

I have a custom object Address. Here in Line 1 (text) there Spanish characters are enterred. How to achieve a translator by a custom setting or any other way for data in salesforce? Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post, it might be useful for you:
[Translate spanish characters to english for field values](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64810/translate-spanish-characters-to-english-for-field-values)